# Shopware 6 error when i run cypress tests

Tags: cypress, shopware, shopware6

When i run cypress tests on my shopware 6.5.6.1 instance i get the following error:

```
cy.request() failed on:
http://localhost/cleanup
The response we received from your web server was:

  > 404: Not Found
```

the error is thrown when running the following line:

```
node_modules/@shopware-ag/e2e-testsuite-platform/cypress/support/commands/system-commands.js:32:1
  30 |     }
  31 | 
> 32 |     return cy.request(`http://${new URL(Cypress.config('baseUrl')).hostname}/cleanup`)
     | ^
  33 |         // ToDo: Remove when cypress issue #5150 is released:
  34 |         //  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/5150/files
  35 |         .its('body').should('eq', 'success');
```

How can i fix this ?